# React-Router: pass props from one component to another using Navlink

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-props

I am using `<NavLink>` for **`routing`** now how can i pass **`props`** into `<NavLink>` to another Component

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On the first component do this

```
<NavLink
     to={{
        pathname:"/priview-data",
        aboutProps:{
              selectedidds:this.state.selectedIds
             }
        }}
        exact
       >Preview Question
</NavLink>
```

and now on another component

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log(props.location.aboutProps);
  }
```

hope it helps

Thanks

Answer (score 13):

The way you can pass data to navigated component using `Link` and `NavLink`

```
<Link to={{
   pathname:'/home',
   state: {name:'from home page'}  
 }}>
  Go to Home
</Link>
```

or using NavLink

```
<NavLink to={{
   pathname:'/home',
   state: {title:'from home page'}  
 }}>
  Go to Home
</NavLink>
```

inside navigated component you can access like this.

if it's hooks

```
import {useLocation} from 'react-router-dom'

    function App(){
      let location = useLocation();
      console.log(location)
      return <h2>...</h2>
    }
```

if it's class based component

```
console.log(this.props.location)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
<NavLink to="/onboarding/profile" state={{ from: "occupation" }}>
  Next Step
</NavLink>
```

Now the only question that remains is, how do we get access to the data on state so we can update the UI based on it? To answer that, we need to look at the component that's being rendered at the **/onboarding/profile** route. For our example, let's call it Profile.

```
    import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'
    
    function Profile () {
      let location = useLocation();
      console.log(location.state.from);
    
      return (
        ...
      )

}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer for more modern React.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use hooks to pass props:

```
<Link
to={{
pathname: "/home",
userProps: {name: "This is a passed prop"},
}}>
Go to home
</Link>
```

To access it from another `component`

```
import { useLocation} from "react-router-dom"

function OtherComponent() {
let location = useLocation();
console.log(location.userProps);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Navlink i do :

```
 <NavLink
     className={`myStyle`}
     to={{pathname: `/mypath`}}
     state={myMessage}
 >
     message
 </NavLink>
```

And i access the state in another component using :

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
 
.../...
 
function toto(){  
let location = useLocation();
console.log (location.state)
```