# How do you pass properties via MenuItemLink in react-admin?

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

Is there a way to pass properties down to components that get loaded via MenuItemLink? I tried using "state" prop to the component that gets loaded via the "to" property in MenuItemLink, but it is returning undefined when I print it out using:

```
const location = useLocation();
console.log('location.state', location.state);
```

Comment: This answer worked. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60123984/react-router-pass-props-from-one-component-to-another-using-navlink

Comment: Maybe the docs could help you: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Menu.html#adding-a-menu-to-a-filtered-list